# as3 array to parameters class / pointer function

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, parameters, function-pointers

I had a little trouble. My case -> I want to set Array as a parameter for caling function/class.

```
var letters:Array = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"];
letters.sort(randomSort);
```

and call function

```
inGame(no1,no2,no3,no4,no5,no6,no7,no8,no9,no10);
```

my function

```
public function inGame(_soal1: String,_soal2: String,_soal3: String,_soal4: String,_soal5: String,_soal6: String,_soal7: String,_soal8: String,_soal9: String,_soal10: String,) 
{
   ......
}
```

The problem -> I cant set array become a parameter for function inGame. Its getting error 1136 when i try like this:

inGame(letters);

any solution for my case??
thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Frank's suggestion, personally I would create another function and call that one with appropriate arguments:

```
public function inGame(...args):void {
    this._inGame.apply(this,(args.length && args[0] is Array) ? args[0] : args);
    /*
    // shorthand for:
    if (args.length && args[0] is Array) {
        this._inGame.apply(this, args[0]);
    } else {
        this._inGame.apply(this, args);
    }
    */
}

private function _inGame(
           _soal1:String, _soal2:String,
           _soal3:String, _soal4:String,
           _soal5:String, _soal6:String,
           _soal7:String, _soal8:String,
           _soal9:String, _soal10:String):void {
    // here's your code
}
```

Comment: @FebriyanMFajar You're welcome. Still, if you're calling this only once, using apply alone shall suffice.

Answer (score 0):

```
inGame.apply(null, letters);
```

see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html#apply%28%29

Comment: Of course you could also rewrite `inGame()` to take an array instead of a lot of arguments...

Answer (score 0):

You should just rewrite your inGame() function :

```
public function inGame(letters:Array):void
{
    // do something with letters
}
```

Unless you have some quality unknown reason not to do this, you are just complicating something rather simple.